# use external htmlhelper extensions with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is it possible to use the System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper extensions with the ServiceStack.Razor implementation.

I'm trying to use the Ext.NET extensions, but others extensions like DevExpress, Kendo have the same problem.

Maybe it's possible to create an instance of a System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper with the correct data and pass that instance to the other extensions and return the result back into ServiceStack.Html.HtmlHelper instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack includes its own Port of MVC HtmlHelper extensions, but these bind to the `ServiceStack.Html` HtmlHelper and not MVC's HtmlHelper which is effectively a distinct, separate concrete implementation.

This results in libraries binding to MVC concrete HtmlHelpers are not interchangeable with libraries binding to ServiceStack's HtmlHelper.

This is not an ideal scenario and shows the limitation of binding to concrete implementations in statically typed languages. A solution would be to have adapters classes provided by Ext.NET, DevExpress, etc that binds to ServiceStack's concrete HtmlHelpers in addition to the MVC HtmlHelper.

The ideal solution would've been for the ASP.NET Framework to include an empty `IHtmlHelper` marker interface (avoiding the dependency on MVC), have all concrete HtmlHelpers implement the same interface and get everyone providing HtmlHelper extensions to bind to the `IHtmlHelper` interface instead.

Comment: Thanks. IHtmlHelper would be the solution, but that's a long timeframe. Anyone tried something already?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You'd have to chase it up with the respective toolkits.

Comment: Any news on this topic?